# Open MediaUpload from external component in Gutenberg

Tags: javascript, block-editor

Gutenberg has MediaUpload component that allows selecting images from media library ([its docs](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/ffd2f7b740099c6c5bb76c68a29b43bd9c090c52/packages/block-editor/src/components/media-upload)).

It allows to pass button to a render property, for example:

```
<MediaUpload
  onSelect={ ( media ) => console.log( 'selected ' + media.length ) }
  allowedTypes={ ALLOWED_MEDIA_TYPES }
  value={ mediaId }
  render={ ( { open } ) => (
    <Button onClick={ open }>
      Open Media Library
    </Button>
  ) }
/>
```

But I also have another component (outside of the render function), doubleclick on it should open the same media library.

```
<AnotherComponent 
  ondoubleclick={ /* how do I open the same media modal here? */ }
></AnotherComponent>
```

Is there some way to do it with a single `<MediaUpload/>` component, or I need multiple?